# Access c# list of objects with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can not figure out why I can't access the result elements.

Whats getting returned:

```
[{"customSurfaceMaster":   {"CSMasterID":1,"CSName":"Q17","QuestionId":12,"OpType":"22","OpFlag":null,"ChartType":"Bar"},"UserCSID":1,"UserId":2,"CSMasterID":1,"PeriodType":null,"PeriodStartValue":null,"PeriodEndValue":null,"ImpLevel":1,"DisplayOrder":1,"Visible":true}]
```

Trying to access here:

```
var Tile = BindTiles(result.customSurfaceMaster.chartType, result.customSurfaceMaster.CSname, result.ImpLevel);
```

The error:

```
 result.customSurfaceMaster is undefined
```

Comment: That's an array, it should be `result[0].customSurfaceMaster` ...

Comment: If you are new to JSON, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) may be helpful. You can tell that it is an array because of the square brackets around it `[]` and then an object by use of squiggly brackets `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var Tile = BindTiles(result.customSurfaceMaster[0].chartType, result.customSurfaceMaster[0].CSname, result.ImpLevel);
```

Comment: I'm glad to help...i usually build my json docs in that way too...and now i was working with a json like `$("#curso").html(data.curso[0].asignatura);`